# Can you define a row and a column mixin in the same css tag in Zurb Foundation?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, mixins

I am working with Zurb Foundation 4 mixins and I was wondering what happens if you put a row and column in the same css tag?

```
header {
          @include grid-row;
          @include grid-column(9);
          }
h1  {
          }
```

Instead of doing something similar to this:

```
header {
          @include grid-row;
          }
h1  {
          @include grid-column(9);
          }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put row and column in the same css selector infact you are going to omit the `.row` or `@include grid-row`(it means `@include grid-column(9)` properties will override on `@include grid-row` property):

```
header { @include grid-row; @include grid-column(9); }
```

equal to:

```
header { @include grid-column(9); }
```

So your columns going to float based on screen size.

When you use `.row` or `@include grid-row` as a separate tag it makes columns going to stand at the center of the page based on `$row-width` size.

Look at this two example with two different codes:

**Example 1:**

```
header {
    @include grid-row;
    @include grid-column(9);
}
```

**Example 1 Output is:**
[image]

**Example 2:**

```
#header {
    @include grid-row;
    h1 {
        @include grid-column(9);
    }
    h2 {
        @include grid-column(3);
    }
}
```

**Example 2 Output is:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I don't understand what you are saying. Can you re-word it to make more sense?